# Electricity generation with diamagnetism

Tags: power-generation, stator

Will a strong diamagnetic material like bismuth allow for electricity generation if the copper coils are on the other side of the bismuth plate from the magnet? Imagine the following three layer system:

Magnet

---

Bismuth or Equivalent Strong Diamagnetic Material

---

Stator

---

Is it at all possible to transfer the flux through bismuth to the stator, assuming a thickness of an inch for instance?

Comment: Please include a drawing, preferably one that shows more details than just the stackup (e.g. axis of rotation, where windings are located, etc)

Comment: Oh I have zero clue how to do axis of rotation or windings, etc. I am simply asking in any case, is it possible to have a magnet rotating or revolving over a thick plate of bismuth with a stator below, such that there is ANY electric generation. I suck at this stuff and wish I could learn more about axis rotation, etc. Any WIKI articles?

Comment: I am trying to prototype an experiment in my garage and failing miserably at it. The concept is awesome, but my execution is shit cause I know nothing. I invested already in a coreless pancake and tried running magnets over it every which direction and seem to not even light up an LED. I'm an idea guy, but I dont want to just give away this idea yet cause I think its legit finally so trying to execute on something I know little about @nanofarad

Comment: Assume that there is just a magnet in the center above the bismuth plates, spinning over 10K rotations per minute. Let's assume there is a pancake stator below the bismuth plate like the one used in windmills (hollow center). The magnet is locked north upwards and south downwards but spins along its equator and is stuck in the center for the most part, not directly over the windings but lets assume i can get the magnet to quadruple the RPM or keep going. At any point like 100K RPM will it generate electricity?

Comment: When you say spinning along its equator, do you mean spinning _around_ its axis? You say the magnet is locked with North always being "up". That is consistent with spinning _around_ its axis. Now, if the the magnet is exactly uniform around its axis, I'm not sure that spinning it  around its axis can induce an electric field. I think that is one of the "Faraday paradoxes" but I need to check on that.

Comment: No amount of spinning will produce any electricity if the magnet is not changing orientation or field strength in relationship to the coil, bismuth or not. You must present a changing magnetic field to the coil to induce any current.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser thank you - this is very helpful. I was hoping to try to generate electricity from levitating a magnet above bismuth and exerting external force via some other force via a solar powered Stirling engine. I guess its fruitless in the current embodiment.

Comment: Diamagnetic effects are several (like 5 or so) orders of magnitude smaller than ferromagnetic effects. It's gonna be hard to compete with iron.